# What are the benefits of Watershed Segmentation in digital image processing?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

What are the real-world (practical) benefits of Watershed Segmentation that's applied to digital images

thanks for all answerers!

Comment: The practical benefit is that it performs segmentation. For more detailed answers I suggest making a more detailed question.
Also, this smells like homework to me.

Comment: @kigurai: no it's really not a homework, but what advantage watershed segmentaion offers?

Comment: Advantage over what? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @HannesOvrén I think the question is: why would one rather use watershed segmentation over another segmentation algorithm?" Any idea's? I suppose the question arises from the fact that the way this algorithm is usually explained to students (including myself when I was one) is at first sight not directly implementable.

Answer (score 0):

Watershed with seeds well chosen can perform segmentation of [objects of interest](http://dip4fish.blogspot.com/) like chromosomes.

Answer (score 0):

this paper is a good material for understanding watershed segmentation and it's uses
Watersheds in digital space: An efficient algorithm based on immersion simulations
also thier is anther one that is good too
The watershed transform: Definitions,algorithms and parallelization strategies

Answer (score 0):

Watershed transformation is a technique for segmentation

This [link](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~beucher/wtshed.html) will help you understand it better